# Loading Plist as Object

Tags: objective-c, plist

Stackoverflow fellows.

I'm trying to load a `plist`. But then `plist`'s `root` can be `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`. Is there prettier way to determine which one it is (by the header's type of `root`) `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`? Obviously, It is very common pull up file from `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` or `NSData`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the `NSPropertyListSerialization` class you can deserialize your plist file from an `NSData` and then with a fast check understand if it's a `NSDictionary` or a `NSArray` through `isMemberOfClass:`

```
id plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data options:0 format:nil error:nil]

if ([plist isMemberOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
  ..
}
```